# Combine unique cell values on a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

See below image of my 3 inputs (columns A:C) and expected out put (column D),

I would like to list the unique values for each row as an output, separated by a comma.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge two rows in excel worksheet where one cell has same content but other cells have different content](https://superuser.com/questions/629493/merge-two-rows-in-excel-worksheet-where-one-cell-has-same-content-but-other-cell)

Answer (score 4):

In cell D1 use :

`=TRIM(A1&IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,B1)>1,"",","&B1)&IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,C1)>1,"",","&C1))`

Then drag down.

If you have more columns, then add `&IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,C1)>1,"",","&C1)` change the C1 to D1 for a fourth column and to E1 for a fifth, and so on.

Also change `A1:C1` in the `COUNTIF` to suit the range of however many columns you may be using.

Comment: Woow It's Working Thanks PeterH But issue is that I have 7 input column then what will be a final formula ?

Comment: See update to answer @RaviBhesadadiya if it works for you accept as correct answer

Comment: Good one @PeterH,  perfect 10 ☺

Answer (score 3):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(COLUMN(A2:C2)=MATCH(A2:C2,A2:C2,0),A2:C2,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This iterates and test if the instance is the first and if so it will add it to the string.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**This simple UDF will help you to combine unique values in cell separated by Comma.**

- Insert this code as Module with the related
  Sheet.

  ```
    Function CombineUnique(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String

    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xDic As Object
    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
    Next
    CombineUnique = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)
    Set xDic = Nothing
    End Function
  ```

**How it works:**

- Before Run this UDF Add **Microsoft
  Scripting Runtime** using **Tools, References**
  in VB Editor window.
- To get desire result, in Cell `D2` write below
  written Formula and fill down.

  `=CombineUnique(A2:C2,",")`

**Note,** *adjust the cell references in Formula
as needed.*

Comment: You are using Late-Binding.  Therefore there is no reason to add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference.  That would only be required if you were using early-binding.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, as precaution it's good to add sometimes I've experienced the error. THANKs for valuable feedback. ☺