# Combine duplicate rows and get to a different cells to new column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table of attendance which look like this,

```
  Name | Date      | Time        |
  abc  | 12/3/2018 | 12:36:11 PM |
  abc  | 12/3/2018 | 08:30:11 PM |
  EFG  | 13/3/2018 | 09:35:11 PM |
  EFG  | 13/3/2018 | 06:23:11 PM |
  EFG  | 13/3/2018 |  9:36:11 PM |
  abc  | 14/3/2018 | 11:36:11 PM |
  GHT  | 14/3/2018 |  3:36:11 PM |
  GHT  | 14/3/2018 | 01:36:11 PM |
  abc  | 15/3/2018 | 10:36:11 PM |
```

What I am trying to do is something like this: get the name and the date (if both duplicates) and, if the name and the date same, need to get the different time to a new cell.

```
  Name | Date      | Time        | new cell    | new cell    |
  abc  | 12/3/2018 | 12:36:11 PM | 08:30:11 PM |
  EFG  | 13/3/2018 | 09:35:11 PM | 06:23:11 PM |  9:36:11 PM |
  abc  | 14/3/2018 | 11:36:11 PM |
  GHT  | 14/3/2018 |  3:36:11 PM | 01:36:11 PM |
  abc  | 15/3/2018 | 10:36:11 PM |
```

So far I tried
[merge two rows in excel worksheet where one cell has same content but other cells have different content](https://superuser.com/questions/629493/merge-two-rows-in-excel-worksheet-where-one-cell-has-same-content-but-other-cell) have different content which is the only solution I came close.

and also tried to export it to Access and write a SQL query to get the above result. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I works guess this is a job for VBa but you specifically tagged worksheet function

Comment: Is there a maximum possible number of records for a name+date?  Are they always sequenced?

Comment: Power Query will be a better choose.

Comment: `D2=IF(A3=A2,C3,"")` `E2=IF(AND(A4=A2,D2<>""),C4,"")` `F2=IF(AND(A5=A2,E2<>""),C5,"")` and so on...

Comment: @fixer1234  Normally,it should be 2 occurrence,Bur sometime an employee can put the finger two -three times accidentally.but if that happen we can count only 2 occurrence and neglect any more records.

Comment: @Akina you have given the answer. You should put it in Answer box.

Answer (score 0):

This is not hard to do with worksheet formulas. 
I assume that your existing “Name”, “Date” and “Time” columns
are Columns `A`, `B` and `C`. 
And I’ll assume that you want to project the data onto a new sheet;
i.e., that you have the data in your first illustration on Sheet1,
and you want the layout of your second illustration on Sheet2. 
Projecting it to another region on the same sheet is the same
except for the details of the formulas. 
In either case, if you want to replace the original data,
you can copy and paste values.

Pick three columns on Sheet1 that you aren’t using; say, `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

- Ensure that cell `X1` is blank (or enter `0` there).
- In cell `X2`, enter `=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2),X1,X1+1)`.
- In cell `Y2`, enter `=MATCH(ROW()-1,X:X,0)`.
- In cell `Z2`, enter `=COUNTIF(X:X,ROW()-1)`.
- Select `X2:Z2` and drag/fill down (at least) as far as you have data.

On Sheet2,

- Enter column headings as desired in Row 1.
- In cell `A2`, enter `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!Y2),"")`.
- In cell `B2`, enter `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!Y2),"")`.
- In cell `C2`, enter `=IF((COLUMN()-COLUMN($C:$C))<Sheet1!$Z2, INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$Y2+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($C:$C))),"")`.
- Select `C2` and drag/fill to the right
  (at least) far enough to cover your data
  (i.e., the maximum number of duplicate rows you have
  for any Name / Date pair).
- Select the filled cells in Row 2
  (i.e., `A2` through the cell you dragged to
  in the previous step) and drag/fill down (at least) far enough
  to cover your data (i.e., the number of unique Name / Date pairs you have).

#### Voilà

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]